# C# http listener not listening on localhost, only works with FQDN

Tags: c#, http, httplistener

*(Please remove the close votes. IMHO this is a valid question, all necessary information is provided and yet tried to brief with all necessary information that's required to identify the possible source of the problem).*

I'm new to C# coming from the Java world. I try to get a simple http server to listen on a port (in my case 8080) on localhost.

I followed this blog post https://codehosting.net/blog/BlogEngine/post/Simple-C-Web-Server.aspx.

When I run the program, it says

[image]

but I cannot reach http://localhost:8080/test/ via browser and `netstat` does not show port 8888 either.
The port is also not blocked by firewall.

Generally, I can run other servers, such as Tomcat, on that port, without a problem. The port is not blocked or used by other applications when I run the C# http server program.

The code:

**Program.cs:**

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    WebServer ws = new WebServer();
    ws.Run();
    Console.WriteLine("A simple webserver. Press a key to quit.");
    Console.ReadKey();
    ws.Stop();  
}
```

**WebServer.cs:**

```
namespace WebServerTest
{
    public class WebServer
    {
        private readonly HttpListener _listener = new HttpListener();
        private readonly Func<HttpListenerRequest, string> _responderMethod;

        public WebServer()
        {
            if (!HttpListener.IsSupported)
                throw new NotSupportedException(
                    "Needs Windows XP SP2, Server 2003 or later.");

            _listener.Prefixes.Add("http://localhost:8080/test/");
            _responderMethod = SendResponse;
            _listener.Start();
        }

        public static string SendResponse(HttpListenerRequest request)
        {
            return string.Format("<HTML><BODY>My web page.<br>{0}</BODY></HTML>", DateTime.Now);
        }

        public void Run()
        {
            ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem((o) =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Webserver running...");

                    while (_listener.IsListening)
                    {
                        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem((c) =>
                        {
                            var ctx = c as HttpListenerContext;

                            string rstr = _responderMethod(ctx.Request);
                            byte[] buf = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(rstr);
                            ctx.Response.ContentLength64 = buf.Length;
                            ctx.Response.OutputStream.Write(buf, 0, buf.Length);


                        }, _listener.GetContext());
                    }


            });
        }

        public void Stop()
        {
            _listener.Stop();
            _listener.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

***=========== Update ===========***

- I changed the port to 8080
- all try-catch-blocks in the code are
  removed
- I made sure that the port is not an issue: I tested to run
  Tomcat servlet container on port 8080 and it works fine (of course,
  now it's stopped again)
- Port 8080 is not blocked by any other
  application nor Firewall

This is what happens when I start the application:

**netstat -na | find "8080"**

```
C:\>netstat -na | find "8080"
  TCP    10.10.1.177:8080       0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
  TCP    192.168.56.1:8080      0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
  TCP    192.168.99.1:8080      0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
```

**I don't understand why nothing is listening at 0.0.0.0:8080 (as it is the case for example when I run Tomcat on port 8080), but on those other IPs.**

However, I cannot access the http server via localhost...

[image]

..or when I try to access via those IP addresses, it's return a "Bad Request" response but not

[image]

I also tried other ports such as 7777 or higher ones 10888.

**ipconfig:**

```
C:\>ipconfig

Windows-IP-Konfiguration

Ethernet-Adapter Ethernet:

   Verbindungsspezifisches DNS-Suffix: mycompany.ch
   Verbindungslokale IPv6-Adresse  . : fe80::5511:3eb5:408a:2562%4
   IPv4-Adresse  . . . . . . . . . . : 10.10.1.177
   Subnetzmaske  . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.254.0
   Standardgateway . . . . . . . . . : 10.10.0.1

Drahtlos-LAN-Adapter WiFi:

   Medienstatus. . . . . . . . . . . : Medium getrennt
   Verbindungsspezifisches DNS-Suffix: mycompany.ch

Ethernet-Adapter VirtualBox Host-Only Network:

   Verbindungsspezifisches DNS-Suffix:
   Verbindungslokale IPv6-Adresse  . : fe80::b4b0:6fc5:d0fc:1c77%24
   IPv4-Adresse  . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.56.1
   Subnetzmaske  . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Standardgateway . . . . . . . . . :

Ethernet-Adapter VirtualBox Host-Only Network #2:

   Verbindungsspezifisches DNS-Suffix:
   Verbindungslokale IPv6-Adresse  . : fe80::b0e6:32c8:fc0a:af52%25
   IPv4-Adresse  . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.99.1
   Subnetzmaske  . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Standardgateway . . . . . . . . . :
```

VirtualBox Adapters should not be a problem for that program, right?

=============

Just to compare it - running a Tomcat on port 8080 on my PC works fine, just like this:

```
C:\>netstat -na | find "8080"
  TCP    0.0.0.0:8080           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
  TCP    [::]:8080              [::]:0                 LISTENING
```

[image]

***=========== Update 2 ===========***

I changed the hostname from `localhost` to the FQDN:

```
_listener.Prefixes.Add("http://devml-nb01-81.mycompany.ch:8080/test/");
```

This way it works.

[image]

But why would it not work via `localhost` (such as Tomcat?)

```
C:\>ping localhost

Ping wird ausgeführt für devml-nb01-81.mycompany.ch [::1] mit 32 Bytes Daten:
Antwort von ::1: Zeit<1ms
Antwort von ::1: Zeit<1ms
Antwort von ::1: Zeit<1ms
Antwort von ::1: Zeit<1ms

Ping-Statistik für ::1:
    Pakete: Gesendet = 4, Empfangen = 4, Verloren = 0
    (0% Verlust),
Ca. Zeitangaben in Millisek.:
    Minimum = 0ms, Maximum = 0ms, Mittelwert = 0ms
```

Comment: I'd start by not swallowing all exceptions, maybe do a `catch (Exception ex) { Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString()); }` so you can see if that's where things are going wrong...

Comment: Can you post 10 line repro code? That should be possible here. Closing for now.

Comment: @Dan Field I removed both try-catch blocks entirely but no exception is thrown.

Comment: I have created a new console application, thrown in your code, it works fine! It binds to localhost:8888 and I'm able to telnet to it or even browse `/test` from FF and returns `My web page.` + timestamp.

Comment: Contrary to your statement, you *do* have something listening on port 8888: "TCP    10.10.100.87:8888      devml-nb01-81:0        ABHÖREN".  Use netstat -ab to find out what it is, if possible.

Comment: @RogerN but thats not localhost's ip, but 10.x.x.x....

Comment: Interesting, the code works great for me, 0.0.0.0:8888 shows up in my netstat and the URL returns the HTML

Comment: I have nothing else running on 8888, and netstat does not list 8888, neither before and after starting the program. I will check further if it's a network related.

Comment: Weird, its true that when I start the program, 10.10.100.87:8888 appears in netstat, but I can neither Telnet that nor localhost:8888.

Comment: Note: if anything else would use that given port, it would throw `System.Net.HttpListenerException`.

Comment: Did you try changing port to anything else higher than say 10000?

Comment: There definitely nothing else using the port. I just changed it to 7777 to be sure. Same results.

Comment: Also tried temp. turning off Windows (and additional security sw) firewall?

Comment: Just tried 10888. i will test with another network and/or PC later.

Comment: Have you reserved the URL using `netsh http add urlacl`?  You might also try listing the existing URL reservations via `netsh http show urlacl` to see if there's a conflict.

Comment: I can use port 8888 for any other application auch as Apache http or Tomcat and it just works fine. So there shouldn't be a problem. I will need to check more later when I'm back home.

Comment: @usr There should be no reason for this question to be closed. All information provided is necessary to solve the issue, and all necessary information is provided (such as code, error logs if any, etc.). Furthermore, I reduced the code, but the rest is necessary to being able to identify the problem.

Comment: I updated my question with my latest findings. The web server works fine when I use the **FQDN**, but it does not work when I use `localhost`. I still don't see why, since Tomcat for example works fine via `localhost`.

Comment: @MathiasConradt What `netsh... urlacl` command did you run? Did you use a `+` sign to indicate any IP or host name?

Comment: @IanMercer I did not run any `netsh` command at all. `netsh http show urlacl` shows me this though - fyi : http://pastebin.com/SAF85MHD

Comment: @IanMercer Tells me invalid syntax. https://snag.gy/e59usq.jpg

Comment: What's the idea behind netsh / reservation of a url? Afaik Tomcat and Apache doesn't do that. Never did that before (at least not explicitly knowing about it) with any other webservers. Tomcat listens fine on  localhost:8888 without any netsh command.

Comment: Open an elevated command prompt and try `netsh http add urlacl url=http://+:8080/ user=EVERYONE`  [sorry, been a while since I had to deal with this awful feature of Windows]  As to why, I assume Tomcat doesn't use http.sys (see http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/437733/Demystify-http-sys-with-HttpSysManager)

Comment: @IanMercer I added it successfully, can even see the entry via `netsh http show urlacl`, but this did not help. I still can't access via localhost, but even more: I cannot access via FQDN either now! See https://snag.gy/KNuwho.jpg After I remove the url via netsh again, I can access via FQDN again. But still no luck at all via localhost.

Comment: With the unreduced code (it's still unreduced) there could be an API usage error. For example nobody knows for sure what prefixes contains. This makes it harder to answer the question.

Comment: @usr Ok, understood. I simplified the constructor and passing of the prefix.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open an elevated command prompt and try

```
netsh http add urlacl url=http://+:8080/ user=EVERYONE
```

(You'll need to use the localized name for EVERYONE or the [SID](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/243330) which is global.)

Applications that use HTTP.sys need reservations. You can read more about that [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/437733/Demystify-http-sys-with-HttpSysManager).

By the way, `localhost` is often problematic in other ways (e.g. some OAuth providers don't allow it). One way around that is to use one of the DNS names that has been mapped to 127.0.0.1 like vcap.me. You can put any name in front: `foo.vcap.me` and it resolves to 127.0.0.1.

Comment: I added the url successfully, can even see the entry via `netsh http show urlacl`, but this did not help. I still can't access via `localhost`, but even more: I cannot access via FQDN either now! See http://snag.gy/KNuwho.jpg After I remove the url via netsh again, I can access via FQDN again. But still no luck at all via `localhost`.

Comment: Ok, I can also use the FQDN in practice, it does not need to be localhost. I was just wondering why the other httpd servers (Tomcat, etc.) were working fine while this one doesn't, even though localhost/127.0.0.1/FQDN all resolve to the same target. Thanks for pointing out that special handling is needed when using HTTP.sys, seems to be HTTP.sys/C#/.NET specific. I will close this question therefore.